# Problemas com o switch

Tags: c++, switch

Estou enfrentando problemas com este código, ao executa-lo o default executa também sendo que em nenhum momento entrei com algum dado diferente do que há nos cases.

```
// faz loop até usuário digitar a sequência de teclas de fim do arquivo
while ((grade = cin.get()) != EOF)
{
    // determina a nota que foi inserida
    switch (grade)
    {
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
           aCount++;
           break;

        case 'B':
        case 'b':
           bCount++;
           break;

        case 'C':
        case 'c':
           cCount++;
           break;

        case 'D':
        case 'd':
           dCount++;
           break;

        case 'F':
        case 'f':
           fCount++;
           break;

        default:
           cout << "Incorrect letter grade entered." << " Enter a new grade." << endl;
    } // fim do switch
} // fim do while
```

Alguém poderia me dizer o que está acontecendo, tem haver com o *buffer* do teclado que pega o `\n` quando entro com os dados? Como resolver isto?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema? tem algo que da para melhorar em alguma das respostas?

Answer (score 1):

A cada vez que você adiciona uma nota, você está adicionando `x\n` ao *buffer*, logo a verificação do `while` executa novamente para `\n`. Recomendo você criar um case especial para `\n` para não ser executado o *default*. Ou recomendo mais ainda você substituir o `(grade = cin.get()) != EOF` por que se não o *buffer* todo sempre vai ser gravado na variável `grade`.

Answer (score 0):

> ...tem haver com o buffer do teclado que pega o `\n` quando entro com os dados? Como resolver isto?

Provavelmente, o [`cin.get`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) deve estar retornando além do caractere digitado, a nova linha também. Uma forma de resolver isto é usar o [`cin.ignore`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/) para ignorar a nova linha:

```
#include <limits>
....

char grade;

while ((grade = cin.get()) != EOF)
{
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); // Ou cin.ignore()
    switch ( grade )
    {
        case 'A':
        case 'a':
           cout << "A" << endl;
           break;
        // ...
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/jSO74p)</kbd>

Uma outra alternativa é:

```
while (cin >> grade)
{
    switch ( grade )
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```